# How do I use cluster analysis in creating a model?

Tags: clustering, modeling, dendrogram

I have a training data set that I've done some cluster analysis on using R's `pvclust` package.  I have a dendrogram of the results and am currently looking for the best way to use the information to create a model(s) of the data.  Can anyone recommend a resource to walk me thru the process of going from clustering to predictive model?  In other words, how do I read a dendrogram to make the most appropriate model(s).

Comment: Some clarification might be helpful.  You say want to build a 'predictive model', what is it you want to predict?  Also, what constitute the data that went into the CA?  A set of explanatory variables, a set of response variables, all the variables you had access to, etc.

Comment: The training data was missing the variable I wanted to predict (a credit event/failure) and I ran the CA on everything else (age, income, lateness, etc.)  The dendrogram normalized the data so that it is on a 0-3 scale.  I'm trying to understand what the dendrogram means.  I basically want to create a model that better predicts whether a person will have a credit failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to proceed is to put the dummies of the clusters & run the regression. For example if there are n cluster groups, then (n-1) cluster dummies & run the regression using these dummies.

Comment: Do you have a link that would describe how to do this in detail?

Comment: Sorry Acesnap I don't have the link. But it's pretty easy to do.